# 'TMP_InputField.Append(string)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to use "Append" funtion from the TMPro namespace in unity. But unable to access it because of it's protection level. This is the function in TMPro "protected virtual void Append(string input)".

Here is the related code to Append function I used;

```
using TMPro;
public TMP_InputField inputField;

if (selectedButton != null && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F1))
{
TextMeshProUGUI buttonText = buttons[(int)selectedButton].GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
string textOnButton = buttonText.text;
inputField.Append(textOnButton);
}
```

Error message: " error CS0122: 'TMP_InputField.Append(string)' is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried just doing: `inputField.text = textOnButton`?
Should do the job.

Comment: What makes you think TextMeshProUGUI  has .Append? its not in the documentation TextMeshProUGUI .text.Append is

Comment: @BugFinder this is actually the requirement of my project that I have to use Append

Comment: @asj Yes I tried this , this works but this doesn't fulfill the requirement of my project.

Comment: @Abubakar what requirement? is this a homework? In that case either A) (and I'm quite sure it is this) `append` does not necessarily refer to you having to use the method `Append` but rather means the text should be appended which string concatenation does .. or B) whoever gave you that task has no idea ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a method is `protected` there is usually a reason why: It is not meant to be used from the outside.

Of course you can hack your way around that using `Reflection` or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76566035/7111561)

---

However, I think in your use case you actually simply want to do either

```
inputField.text += textOnButton;
```

which will trigger events or

```
inputField.SetTextWithoutNotify(inputfield.text + textOnButton);
```

if you don't want events to be triggered

Answer (score 0):

Create the following class within the same project with calling code:

```
public class DerivedInputField : TMP_InputField
{
    public new void Append(string input)
    {
        base.Append(input);
    }
}
```

Then use this class like:

```
var inputField = new DerivedInputField();
inputField.Append("test");
```

Comment: But I have a "public TMP_InputField input field" which I used to assign a TMP input field in the unity inspector. but if change it to " public DerivedInputField inputField" This doesn't allow me to assign the input field in the inspector. I am new to unity, please bear with me.

Comment: @Abubakar well you would need to actually remove the `TMP_InputField` from your gameobject and instead add this new component to it and then reassign all the relevant fields